# Almacenar los valores de un input en un fichero con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Me podríais ayudar por favor con un proyecto que tengo que hacer en html?. El proyecto consiste en hacer un formulario de usuario y contraseña bastante sencillito. El problema viene a la hora de recoger los valores introducidos en el formulario y almacenaros en un fichero aparte. Me he pasado todo la mañana peleándome con javascript debido a que es la primera vez que lo uso.
Les adjunto a continuación el formulario y espero una respuesta. De antemano gracias.

```
      <form action="" id="form"> 
        <input type="text" name="usr" value="" id="usr" placeholder="Teléfono, usuario o correo electrónico">
        <input type="password" name="psw" value="" id="input2" placeholder="Contraseña">
        <button type="submit" onclic="getData()">Iniciar sesion</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: 1. `onclic` no existe, seguramente quisiste escribir `onclick`.
2. Hasta donde sé, no puedes escribir o crear archivos desde el navegador con JS, ¿podrías ahondar más en cómo quieres lograr eso? Como ya se mencionó en una respuesta, lo puedes hacer si tienes un servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Primero necesitas recoger la información del formulario. Si quieres hacerlo con Javascript, puedes utilizar ajax. Pero además de eso, vas a necesitar algún lenguaje en la parte del servidor, que sea el encargado de procesar y almacenar esa información.

Puedes utilizar php o node para la parte del servidor.

Ejemplo para el envío:

```javascript
function enviarFormulario(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            alert("Datos guardados!");
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "./guardar.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("usr=usu1&psw=1234");
}

const form = document.forms.miformulario;
form.addEventListener('submit', enviarFormulario);
```